# Split an array element into set of strings

Tags: ruby, arrays

how do we split a line(s) into set of strings
Input

```
array = ["123 abcd ki98 1090:09 12/1/2098", "678 njiu ji87 1087:90 87/56/90"]
```

desired output

```
array =[["123", "abcd", "ki98", "1090:09", "12/1/2098"],
["678", "njiu", "ji87", "1087:90", "87/56/90"]]
```

I've tried

```
array.each do |line|
  array2 << line.split(' ') # doesnt give what I wanted
  array2 << line.split(/\s+/) # doesnt give me what I wanted
  array2 << line.split/\s+/ # comes with error
  array2 << line.split(/\s+/).inspect # This works but is too slow
end
```

any suggestions to fix this - just started ruby. Please help.

Comment: please [indent your code](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) with 4 spaces

Comment: Desired output is unclear, do youw ant an array of arrays? (You've got unclosed brackets)

Comment: You're missing a pair of brackets if you want an array of arrays, i.e. `[["123", "..."], ["678", "..."]]`. Furthermore your output variable should be called `arrays` (plural).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> a.map(&:split).flatten
# => ["123", "abcd", "ki98", "1090:09", "12/1/2098678", "njiu", "ji87", "1087:90", "87/56/90"]
```

**EDIT**

If you need an array of arrays

```
array = ["123 abcd ki98 1090:09 12/1/2098", "678 njiu ji87 1087:90 87/56/90"]

array.map &:split
# => [["123", "abcd", "ki98", "1090:09", "12/1/2098"], ["678", "njiu", "ji87", "1087:90", "87/56/90"]
```

Comment: Instead of `map` and `flatten` you may want to use [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map).

Comment: @sqummer `a.map(&:split)` is a shorthand for `a.map { |l| l.split }`

Comment: When I do this, I get
    <top (required)>': undefined method `&' for #<Enumerator: 
any thoughts?

Comment: an update: this works fine on individual array elements but not on an array itself ... example

     a[1].map &map:split # works fine

however, if you do put this in a loop  
    a.each do |line|
    different_array << line.map &:split
    end
it comes up with error message 
    `map': undefined method `split' for 

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you are calling on individual items, no need of map

Comment: Excellent - Thanks Santosh. I think I know where I'am doing wrong ... I was trying to modify each line and copy to another array - didnt work....  however, array.map! &:split has removed the pain of storing it another array...while doing its job... Appreciate your help mate

Answer (score 2):

And another solution:

```
a.flat_map(&:split)
```

Comment: hi, when I do this , I get 
    123 abcd ki98 1090:09 12/1/2098
    678 njiu ji87 1087:90 87/56/90

how do we get 
    
    [["123", "abcd", "ki98", "1090:09", "12/1/2098"],
    ["678", "njiu", "ji87", "1087:90", "87/56/90"]]